# Surfactant micelles from glassware

Tags: electrochemistry, cleaning

FYI to start- I'm not a chemist by training, so assume I'm missing some basic knowledge of the field.

I've been trying to do some electrodeposition with an iridium tetrachloride-based solution, and my success at doing so is random at best. In talking to a chemist, they suggested that I buy new glassware and perform nitric acid or sulfuric acid cleaning on all of my glassware; according to them, my cleaning the glassware with regular dish soap (I've been using Dawn) has most likely coated everything in surfactants and those are releasing micelles of surfactant into all of my solutions.

I believe what this person is telling me, as I can read about surfactants forming micelles. However, in a search of both academic (e.g. Scopus) and non-academic sources (read: Google), I can't find any  detailed information on this issue, or its prevention, in lab settings; I also can't find details about how these surfactant micelles actually affect a process like electrodeposition. I seem to only be able to find random informal glassware cleaning SOPs from different labs, but no good reading on surfactant contamination in electrochemistry experiments.

Am I searching the wrong keywords? Is this too broad a question? Is this just common knowledge among chemists because of their knowledge base?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, yes, consider this a common knowledge. Surfactant contamination **is** a thing.

Comment: @PoGami, Is this a part of a formal academic research project or just a home experiment? The actual glassware cleaning systems are too dangerous, they are used where really clean glassware is needed. On the other hand, micelle can only form under a certain concentration and they cannot permanently stick to glass. You might have surfactant contamination due to improper rinsing but not as micelles.

Comment: @M.Farooq - I view it a bit differently. I'd absolutely believe that the surface of the glassware could be contaminated, that the contaminating molecules could go into solution and then form micelles in the solution.   I totally agree that micelles themselves are not going to be sticking to the glassware and then dissolve into the solution.

Comment: @MaxW, But remember that micelles can only be formed when the surfactant conc. exceeds the critical micelle concentration *in solution.* Suppose a clean glassware has been washed several times, by no means, it can exceed critical micelle concentration in a solution. Yes there will be surfactant in solution but in ppm levels or even less.

Comment: @M.Farooq: yes, this is formal research being carried out in an academic lab. I've viewed SDS' and have done the cleaning in a fume hood with proper secondary storage.

Comment: @PoGaMi, In order to get rid of surfactants from glass surfaces one can wash or rather soak glassware in 1 M sodium hydroxide for 15-20 min (Caution with eyes and skin) followed by copious amounts of deionized water. I am assuming no other electrode or metallic part will come in contact with base and the glassware is standard borosilicate glass. Remember, dishwashing detergent is the worst thing to use for electrochemical work. There are specialized detergents such as Alconox. Even they should not be used for electrochemistry but still better than liquid soap which sticks forever.

Comment: @M.Farooq - got it, thank you, I'll try it if the nitric acid wash I did already doesn't end up working. I guess my original question still stands, though- other than just the understanding that "surfactants eventually form micelles and bind to things", is there any more formal literature where I can read about why this affects processes like electrodeposition?

Comment: I am not familiar with electrodeposition but dealt a lot with surfactants affecting silica capillaries. Our standard protocol was to wash the silica capillary with strong base rather than acid to get rid of micelles. Keep in mind that surfactants affect the resistance or better conductivity of the solution. Search conductivity of micellar media.